# Firebase Phone Auth for private product

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have a private product and I use Firestore to store my data. I want the most convey for my users so I decided to use Firebase phone number authentication. But the problem is everyone who knows the product can use their phone number to login as a valid user. So how could I control who can login?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent users from logging in with Firebase Authentication. All they need to do this is the configuration data, which you by definition have to include in the app itself.

What you **can** do is prevent the users from:

1. using your app.
2. accessing the data your app uses.

If you're using Firebase's Realtime Database, Firestore, or Cloud Storage, you can accomplish the second one by writing [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) that are automatically executed by Firebase, and control access to the data. If you're using another way to expose the data to your app, you will need to [verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) of the user in a secure environment, and ensure they're authorized to access the data.

To prevent the user from using your app, you'll typically detect whether they are authorized in your application code. If they're not, sign them out, and redirect them back to the sign-in screen. When combines with the data access controls described above, you can effectively control abuse.